TESTONLY_AND_VISIBILITY Undefined identifier while building Devtools-frontend [version 6312]
While building devtools-frontend i am facing this error
    forward_variables_from(invoker, "*", TESTONLY_AND_VISIBILITY)
                                         ^----------------------
See //build/toolchain/gcc_toolchain.gni:906:3: whence it was called.
  gcc_toolchain(target_name) {
  ^---------------------------
See //build/toolchain/linux/BUILD.gn:11:1: whence it was called.
clang_toolchain("clang_ppc64") {
^-------------------------------
See //BUILD.gn:19:1: which caused the file to be included.
group("devtools_all_files") {
^----------------------------

Also this used to work on my machine. Not sure what broke. There must be some dependency thats changed. Any idea what could cause this?

This got fixed by running gclient sync
